# Sensor in Apple Logo at the Back of iMac

Tags: imac, hardware

I am cleaning and preferrably washing the iMac aluminium casing. I have removed all the hardware from the iMac except the sensor placed at the back side where Apple logo is. I would like to know what exactly is that sensor and if it could be removed?

I tried exhaustive search but it appears that all roads lead to dead end. So I would like to ask the type of the sensor and can it be removed? My guess is that it is ambient light sensor but I am not sure.

[image]

Comment: Where on the logic board did it go to?  Please post a pic of that. Of the iMacs I’ve disassembled that was an antenna, not a sensor

Comment: @Allan yes, its an antenna as per the answer from jksoegaard, Wifi antenna. I am not sure where on the logic board it goes as I have dismantaled the whole iMac.  I want to know if this antenna can be disassembled as I want to wash the casing. Or I can simply cover the hole where the wire comes out and wash thoroughly.

Comment: @Allan my guess is that it is stuck with glue just like the power switch in the iMac's

Comment: Yes.  There’s no “mechanicals” so there’s nothing to break.  Finding proper glue will be s pain though do don’t remove it

Comment: @Allan yup I thought so. Just covered the tiny hole from where the wires came out with tape and gave a thorough wash to the casing. Everything seems fine. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not list which model of iMac you're cleaning, but in general the alu iMac models do not have a sensor in the back logo. Perhaps you're talking about the WiFi antenna that is located there on some models - you could ofcourse argue that an antenna is a type of sensor.

If you're actually talking about the front Apple logo, then older iMacs had an IR-sensor there for taking input from the Apple Remote.

Comment: Yes I am talking about the antenna at the back. The model is 2010 21". Is there any way to remove it? Or is it likely to go bad if I wash chean the aluminium casing?